# How to display the replies count of the each user comments with show/hide option in node view page in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-comments

```
Now, I am having comments section like this in node view page.

  Comment 1
    comment 11
    comment 12
  Comment 2
  Comment 3
    comment 31
    comment 32
    comment 33

But, I would to show this with show/hide option for replied comments with replies count. like below

  Comment 1
    show/hide 2 replies
    ------------------
    | comment 11     |
    | comment 12     | 
    ------------------
  Comment 2
  Comment 3
    show/hide  3 replies
    ---------------
    |  comment 31 |
    |  comment 32 |
    |  comment 33 |
    ---------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the count of comments in your Template with

```
<?php print $comment_count; ?>
```

And for Show and Hide, whats about the simple .hide() and .show() jQuery Functions?